# How can I fix this floating gap with the softbody collision?

Tags: physics, soft-body

[image]

I know this may seem like a minor complaint, but it annoys me that the collision thickness for this plane is minimum to 0.001 which leaves this very small floating space between the softbody-ball and the plane. Is there any fix to make the ball touch all the way to the plane or is it simply a software limitation?

Comment: so i am really curious what comments and answers you will get here... :D i lean back and will eat my popcorn....

Comment: is there a Collision Margin for Soft Body? Doesn't look like

Comment: Instead of add physic directly to the table. Make a proxy mesh then you can full control the gap. I don't know why there is a 0.001 gap, sorry.